# Expected value of quotient of Poisson distributions

Tags: poisson-distribution, expected-value, independence, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables such that 
$X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda \cdot c)$ and $Y \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda \cdot (1-c))$, where $c$ is a real number in $[0, 1]$.

Is there an easy way of proving that $E\left[\frac{X}{X + Y} | X + Y > 0\right] = c$?
Numerical computations I made indicate that this is true.

Comment: Google "Poisson thinning."

Comment: Aha!
We can define Z := X + Y and see X as a thinning of Z with probability c.
Then given any outcome of Z, conditional on Z, X is binomially distributed with parameters (Z, c), which has expected value c* Z. So for each Z!=0, E[X/Z | Z] = c. So E[X/Z | Z > 0] =  c.

Correct?